# How do I dockerize already built rasa project?

Tags: docker, rasa, docker-engine

I have built my rasa project and have added in my github repository.
Now I want to dockerize it.

How do I do that?

Most of the dockerization tutorials I see, start docker before building project.

Answer (score 0):

There's a full course on Rasa deployments that explains how to combine Docker and Rasa in full detail.

To dockerize a Rasa assistant from scratch you may enjoy [this explainer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UwEbGVjwEg&list=PL75e0qA87dlHmfmu7oPPYA22fmc6GJ2aW&index=2), if you're interested in using the pre-made Rasa containers you may enjoy [this one instead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1FCsQ271DA&list=PL75e0qA87dlHmfmu7oPPYA22fmc6GJ2aW&index=3).